# Does PHP mysqli query and fetch_(row/assoc) use real time data?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When we use PHP mysqli->query() and then fetch_row/fetch_assoc in a loop, does PHP cache the data first and give back result as whole (and hence if the row is updated in the meantime, the fetch_row() still returns old data? or does it give us real time data?

Is there any place where we can set this behaviour (e.g. setting database type, php config...?) so that we can control whether PHP should use cached data or real-time data as desire.

For example, we have 2 processes that modify the same DB table 'users':

file 1:

```
<?php
$res=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 0 and id < 100 ORDER BY id ASC");
while($r=$res->fetch_assoc()){
    ...do something that takes 10 mins each loop...
    print_r($r['active']);
}
```

file 2:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET `active` = 'TRUE' where id = 90");
```

Let say initially all users are having `active` set to FALSE. 
We run file 1 on one terminal, then run file 2 right after that on another terminal.

At the time when file 1 comes to process the user "90", does it print out "TRUE" or "FALSE"?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not about PHP, it's about the database. The regular kind relational databases run a query and return consistent results at once. When you read the results doesn't matter, they're just there. Nothing you do while the query is running or after it changes the results. The same isn't true for certain other kind of databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 0 and id < 100 ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Your query was executed ***only*** on that step. How you access the data after that does not make PHP query the records again. The loop that you're running is on a PHP internal variable that holds all the data returned by the query. There is no further communication with MySQL Server during your loop.

If records are changed after your query and before your display, you will see old data displayed. Not realtime.

To get the latest data which might have been updated by another process during this period (and we're usually talking micro/milli/whatever seconds here), you need to query again.

> At the time when file 1 comes to process the user "90", does it print out "TRUE" or "FALSE"?

`FALSE`

Because when you queried the database it was set to `FALSE` and it doesn't matter what the current value is unless you query again.

Comment: There may or may not be communication with the database during the loop… that depends on whether the query is buffered or not and how quickly the data was fetched from the database. But that's really an irrelevant detail. The database itself takes care of the [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties of the query and how (in)consistent the returned data is.

Comment: Also there are quite some indicators in the post that indicate the OP is not familiar with query buffering or ACID that's why I left those topics out.

Comment: Sweeping ACID under the rug doesn't seem very educational. :-P